# Android: trouble with bindService() -> service is null

Tags: android, android-service, android-binder

I'm having a problem with binding service to an activity. I get playing_service==null. I can't find what I'm doing wrong. Why is playing_service null??

**MyActivity class:**

```
private playService playing_service=null;

private ServiceConnection service_conn=new ServiceConnection(){
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        LocalBinder binder=(LocalBinder)service;
        playing_service=binder.getService();
    }
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

public void playTrack(View view){       
        Intent i=new Intent(this,playService.class);
        i.setAction("com.c0dehunter.soundrelaxer.PLAY");
        bindService(i,service_conn,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        if(playing_service==null) //here I get true,
             //if I try to access playing_service I get NullPointerException

    }
}
```

**playService class:**

```
private final IBinder binder=new LocalBinder();

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){       
     return 1; //dummy
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return binder;
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder{
    public playService getService(){
        return playService.this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your service might not be null because binding a service is an `asynchronous` method, so instead of checking the availability of your service yet after calling the bind method, you should do it in your service connection implementation, for e.g.:

```
private ServiceConnection service_conn=new ServiceConnection(){
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        LocalBinder binder=(LocalBinder)service;
        playing_service=binder.getService();

        if(playing_service != null){
            Log.i("service-bind", "Service is bonded successfully!");

            //do whatever you want to do after successful binding
        }
    }
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

Comment: Wow, thak you. Been smashing my head against the wall for hours.

Comment: One more thing though - when I call playTrack() for the second time, OnServiceConnected() doesn't get invoked anymore. Why is this?

The way I'm killing the first service is with playing_service.stopPlaying() which also calls selfStop().

Comment: But I exited that service with selfStop()!?

Comment: you need to call unbind method to gracefully terminate this relationship

Comment: @Onik Sure. I've added `serviceconnection` which should be a relative synonym.